# com.android.log4j version 1(1.2.17) - (didn't want to upgrade it) is not supporting with latest gradlew version : 7.0.2

Tags: java, android, logging, log4j, release-builds

It is working with the Debug mode and Signed Debug APK also, but when I create the Signed Release APK, the build was successful but it crashes when I open it.

Here is the error and warning after installing and opening the Signed released APK :

----------ERROR-----------

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                     Process: com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub, PID: 2969                                                                                                     java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError                                                                                                      at x.e.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0)                                                                                                       at x.f.get(:1)                                                                                                      at w2.a.get(Unknown Source:13)                                                                                                      at y.b.get(:1)                                                                                                      at w2.a.get(Unknown Source:13)                                                                                                      at t.a.get(:7)                                                                                                      at w2.a.get(Unknown Source:13)                                                                                                      at x.c.get(:5)                                                                                                      at w2.a.get(Unknown Source:13)                                                                                                      at c0.b.get(:1)                                                                                                         at w2.a.get(Unknown Source:13)                                                                                                      at e0.c.d(:49)                                                                                                      at e0.c.c(:7)                                                                                                       at o3.f.b(:1)                                                                                                       at x3.a.c(Unknown Source:9)                                                                                                         at o3.f.b(:1)                                                                                                       at n1.e.<init>(Unknown Source:4)                                                                                                        at com.bletag.mqtt.HiveMqttClient.startMqtt(:21)                                                                                                        at com.coolrgroup.virtualhub.Login.onCreate(Unknown Source:361)                                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)                                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)                                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)                                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)                                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)                                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find '[toLeakAwareBuffer]' in z2.b                                                                                                         at h3.q.a(Unknown Source:130)                                                                                                       at z2.b.<clinit>(Unknown Source:8)                                                                                                      at x.e.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0)                                                                                                       at x.f.get(:1)                                                                                                          at w2.a.get(Unknown Source:13)                                                                                                          at y.b.get(:1)                                                                                                          at w2.a.get(Unknown Source:13)                                                                                                          at t.a.get(:7)                                                                                                          at w2.a.get(Unknown Source:13)                                                                                                          at x.c.get(:5)                                                                                                          at w2.a.get(Unknown Source:13)                                                                                                          at c0.b.get(:1)                                                                                                         at w2.a.get(Unknown Source:13)                                                                                                          at e0.c.d(:49)                                                                                                          at e0.c.c(:7)                                                                                                       at o3.f.b(:1)                                                                                                       at x3.a.c(Unknown Source:9)                                                                                                         at o3.f.b(:1)                                                                                                       at n1.e.<init>(Unknown Source:4)                                                                                                        at com.bletag.mqtt.HiveMqttClient.startMqtt(:21)                                                                                                        at com.coolrgroup.virtualhub.Login.onCreate(Unknown Source:361)                                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)                                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)                                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)                                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)                                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)                                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)                                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

-----------WARNING AFTER THIS ERROR (LOG4J CLASS NOT FOUND)--------------

```
log4j:WARN Caught Exception while in Loader.getResource. This may be innocuous. 2023-06-06 10:59:52.864  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError 2023-06-06 10:59:52.869  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W   at m4.g.a(Unknown Source:8) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.869  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      at m4.g.b(Unknown Source:60) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.869  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W     at k4.k.<clinit>(Unknown Source:56) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.869  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      at k4.k.a(Unknown Source:0) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.869  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      at com.coolrgroup.virtualhub.Login.<init>(:2) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.869  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.870  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.870  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2696) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.870  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.870  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.870  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.870  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.870  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.870  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.870  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.870  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.870  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.871  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader 2023-06-06 10:59:52.871  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.871  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.871  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.871  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W   at m4.g.a(Unknown Source:0) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.871  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      ... 16 more 2023-06-06 10:59:52.872  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub-H48SnYDjkBBiZSDa0fRsqA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub-H48SnYDjkBBiZSDa0fRsqA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]] 2023-06-06 10:59:52.872  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.872  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.872  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.873  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W     ... 20 more 2023-06-06 10:59:52.878  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W  log4j:WARN Caught Exception while in Loader.getResource. This may be innocuous. 2023-06-06 10:59:52.878  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError 2023-06-06 10:59:52.878  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W   at m4.g.a(Unknown Source:8) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.878  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      at m4.g.b(Unknown Source:60) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.878  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W     at k4.k.<clinit>(Unknown Source:64) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.878  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      at k4.k.a(Unknown Source:0) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.878  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      at com.coolrgroup.virtualhub.Login.<init>(:2) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.878  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.878  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.878  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2696) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.878  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W   at m4.g.a(Unknown Source:0) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.879  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W      ... 16 more 2023-06-06 10:59:52.880  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub-H48SnYDjkBBiZSDa0fRsqA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub-H48SnYDjkBBiZSDa0fRsqA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]] 2023-06-06 10:59:52.880  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.880  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) 2023-06-06 10:59:52.880  3026-3026  System.err              com.coolrgroup.coolrvirtualhub       W     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Previously my gradle version is 3.3.1 and in that version the DEBUG build is also not creating it was showing error of class not found for com.andorid.log4j.logger... so i have to change the versions and create build again.
then I upgraded gradle to latest version and build, the build was creating and running on debug, also signed DEBUG but not working on SIGNED RELEASE BUILD APK

here is my gradle files
-----------/Build.gradle--------------

```
apply plugin: 'HIDDEN'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'platform'
            keyPassword 'mypass'
            storeFile file('../storeFile/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'mypass'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        resConfigs "en"
        applicationId "HIDDEN"
        multiDexEnabled false
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }
    splits {
        // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
        abi {
            // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
            enable true

            // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
            // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.
            reset()

            // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
            include "armeabi-v7a"

            // Specifies that we want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk false
        }

        density {
            enable false
            // Exclude these densities when building multiple APKs.
            exclude "ldpi", "tvdpi", "xxxhdpi", "400dpi", "560dpi"
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            pseudoLocalesEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27+'
    implementation files('libs/joda-time-2.4.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/BLETag/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/BLETag/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0'
    //implementation files('libs/BLETag/mobileservices-1.1.5.jar')
    // implementation files('libs/BLETag/notifications-1.0.1.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/androidlelibrary.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.3.5.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.5.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')
    implementation files('libs/bluetooth le library.jar')
    implementation files('libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar')
    implementation files('libs/EasyCursor-0.1.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/android-logging-log4j-1.0.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.7.jar')
    //implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
    implementation files ('libs/gson-2.3.jar')
    implementation "com.hivemq:hivemq-mqtt-client:1.3.0"
}
```

------------- /build.gradle ----------------

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
        tasks.each { task ->
            if (task.name.equals('mockableAndroidJar')) {
                task.enabled = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```